# android_intent Error First Install Flutter Plugin

Tags: gradle, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

This is the first time I installed the Android_intent plugin in my application,During the experiment I installed plugins in a simple application and the plugin went well, but when I did the same thing in the application I actually had a plugin that no longer worked. but when I installed it an error like this appeared:

```
/home/denis/AndroidStudioProjects/spmi_conference/build/android_intent/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:23: error: duplicate class: io.flutter.plugins.androidintent.AndroidIntentPlugin
public class AndroidIntentPlugin implements MethodCallHandler {
       ^
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:13: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
                               ^
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:14: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
                               ^
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:15: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
                                             ^
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:16: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
                                             ^
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:17: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
                                              ^
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
public class AndroidIntentPlugin implements MethodCallHandler {
                                            ^
  symbol: class MethodCallHandler
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
  private final Registrar mRegistrar;
                ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class AndroidIntentPlugin
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
  public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class AndroidIntentPlugin
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
  private AndroidIntentPlugin(Registrar registrar) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class AndroidIntentPlugin
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:117: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                           ^
  symbol:   class MethodCall
  location: class AndroidIntentPlugin
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:117: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                                            ^
  symbol:   class Result
  location: class AndroidIntentPlugin
/home/denis/AndroidStudioProjects/spmi_conference/build/android_intent/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:13: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
                               ^
/home/denis/AndroidStudioProjects/spmi_conference/build/android_intent/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:14: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
                               ^
/home/denis/AndroidStudioProjects/spmi_conference/build/android_intent/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:15: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
                                             ^
/home/denis/AndroidStudioProjects/spmi_conference/build/android_intent/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:16: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
                                             ^
/home/denis/AndroidStudioProjects/spmi_conference/build/android_intent/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:17: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
                                              ^
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    final MethodChannel channel =
          ^
  symbol:   class MethodChannel
  location: class AndroidIntentPlugin
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        new MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "plugins.flutter.io/android_intent");
            ^
  symbol:   class MethodChannel
  location: class AndroidIntentPlugin
/home/denis/Documents/DENISDATA/Jobs/2018/test/flutter/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/android_intent-0.3.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/androidintent/AndroidIntentPlugin.java:116: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
20 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android_intent:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried this for several days.
am I wrong with my code?
can someone help me? thank you
best regards.

Comment: I think you should better raise this issue in github

Comment: thanks for your answer and edit suggestion.
I have sent this issue on Github, but there has been no reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code into your project's android build Gradle file.

```
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->

        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.1"
        }


      }
   }
}
```

Dont forget to clean your project before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with another plugin, and found little useful information. The steps that ultimately worked for me were to:

1. Upgrade the version of gradle:

   - In `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` I switched to using 5.4.1
   - In `android/build.gradle` I switched to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'`
2. Ensuring that AndroidX support libraries are used:

   - In `android/app/build.gradle` this was a matter of switching all `android.support` prefixes to `androidx.support` (and `com.android.support` to `com.androidx.support`, respectively).

Based on my experimentation, I believe it is #2 that is the root cause of the problem - indeed, step #1 may be entirely unnecessary, but seemed like a reasonable place to start while I was trying to figure out what the problem was.

As you did not provide information about your gradle properties, I can only assume that you are facing a similar issue based on the similarity in build issues encountered.